# Facebook SDK import issues with Session and SessionState

Tags: android, facebook, import, session-variables, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am relatively new to the android Facebook SDK and need help setting up my login activity after spending fruitless days on this. I am unable to resolve the issues and each time I try and import com.facebook.Session (as recommended in the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate), it is automatically changed to "SessionState" instead, which again doesn't help resolve the errors. Please can someone help me fix this.

I am using facebook sdk v3.6 and the latest ADT and SDK tools. Also, my facebook SDK is in a different folder (with the android SDK) and the project exists in a seperate workspace (again, as recommeneded by the tutorial, I did not choose to copy the fb sdk into my workspace, simply imported it). All the FB samples are working fine, I tried copying the code from Scrumptious's main activity to get my login working.

Here's the code for reference:

```
package com.example.myproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService.Session;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;


public class FBLoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY = "user_skipped_login";

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS +1;

    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
    private MenuItem settings;
    private boolean isResumed = false;
    private boolean userSkippedLogin = false;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    /* Errors on the next line:
    Multiple markers at this line
- Session.StatusCallback cannot be resolved to a type
- Session.StatusCallback cannot be resolved to a type
- Watchpoint:FBLoginActivity [access and modification] - 
 callback */
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            userSkippedLogin = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY);
        }
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SplashFragment splashFragment = (SplashFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SPLASH] = splashFragment;
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();

        splashFragment.setSkipLoginCallback(new SplashFragment.SkipLoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSkipLoginPressed() {
                userSkippedLogin = true;
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;

        // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in analytics and advertising reporting.  Do so in
        // the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY, userSkippedLogin);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open, try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            userSkippedLogin = false;
        } else if (userSkippedLogin) {
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen and ask the user to login, unless the user explicitly skipped.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
        if (fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            settings = null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.equals(settings)) {
            showSettingsFragment();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void showSettingsFragment() {
        showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            // check for the OPENED state instead of session.isOpened() since for the
            // OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED state, the selection fragment should already be showing.
            if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED)) {
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was resolved by removing the statement

```
import android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService.Session;
```

and instead adding:

```
import com.facebook.Session;
```

Comment: It worked for me though and I did find another related post somewhere that dealt with a similar FB issue.